# Currency Exchange would come under which domain?

Tags: dns

I worked in a project that managed the currency exchange process for a firm. In our organization this project was tagged under Diversified Unit, but I'm wondering under which domain should it be categorized. Financial Services? Retail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it'll come under the finance domain.